# What's the Legendre of zero?

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I know that this question may look like meaningless, but through solving a question, I encountered with this form of Legendre.
$ P_{l}(0)$ or a sum over it. You have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Use the generating function, with $\ds{\verts{h}\ <\ 1}$,
$\ds{{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}
     =\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{\infty}h^{\ell}\,{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{x}}$ such that:

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{\infty}h^{\ell}\,{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{0}
&={1 \over \root{1 + h^{2}}}=\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose \ell}h^{2\ell}
=\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\ell - 1/2 \choose \ell}\pars{-1}^{\ell}h^{2\ell}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{{\vphantom{\LARGE A}\ell\ =\ 0 }\atop \ell\ \mbox{even}}^{\infty}
{\ell/2 - 1/2 \choose \ell/2}\pars{-1}^{\ell/2}h^{\ell}    
\end{align}

> Then,

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\,{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{0}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & \ell\ \mbox{is odd}
\\[2mm]
\pars{-1}^{\ell/2}{\bracks{\ell - 1}/2 \choose \ell/2}
& \mbox{if} & \ell\ \mbox{is even}
\end{array}\right.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prove that

$$P_{{L}} \left( 0 \right) ={\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{L}
{_2F_1(-L,-L;\,1;\,-1)}}{{2}^{L}}}
$$

Please look the equation (35) at  [Legendre Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html)

It is possible to obtain the simplified form

$$P_{{L}} \left( 0 \right) = \left( -1 \right) ^{L}{-1/2\choose L/2}$$